# Nginx redirect to a specific page if the url contains ?"<script>

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to make sure if anyone after my domain name (www.xxxxxx.com/) types the following ?"
i.e URL entered would be www.xxxxxx.com/?"
I want that user to get redirected to a different page www.yyyyy.com

What should be done at Nginx.conf to achieve this

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Detecting a query string consisting of a only a double quote character can be achieved by looking for its URL encoded representation (`%22`) in the `$args` or `$request_uri` varaiables.

```
if ($request_uri = '/?%22') { return 301 /; }
```

Or:

```
location = / {
    if ($args = '%22') { return 301 /; }
    ...
}
```